# Is there a way to accept an argument in a cython function without explicitly specifying its type?

Tags: python, types, cython, void-pointers

I am a newbie to Cython. I am trying to write a function that can accept either a tuple or list as an argument.

I understand that passing a void* argument to a C++ function allows us to do this (though I might be wrong), but is there a similar way to do this for Cython?

Is there a way to merge the following into one by not having to explicitly mention `tuple` or `list`? -

```
def shape_func(tuple a, tuple b) :
    return (a[0] > b[0])

def shape_func(list a, list b) :
    return (a[0] > b[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use no type at all, i.e., write it as if it were a normal python function, or `object`.  In either case, any python object (`PyObject*`) will be accepted.

```
def shape_func(a, b):
    return (a[0] > b[0])
```